# can't use "." on all vscode interface v: 1.78.0

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I recently installed git on my computer as I'm taking a course on how to monitor repositories in git. What happens is that after installing it I can no longer use the dot anywhere in the interface, not even when writing html code. I get a `command " not found` error, I thought it was a shortcut error but nothing.

The interface was working perfectly before installing the git on windows. After using it I get that command error and it is impossible even to edit the file type on the workspace.

[image]

vscode version: 1.78.0

code --list-extensions:

```
code --install-extension akamud.vscode-theme-onedark
code --install-extension alefragnani.project-manager
code --install-extension christian-kohler.path-intellisense
code --install-extension dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
code --install-extension esbenp.prettier-vscode
code --install-extension formulahendry.auto-close-tag
code --install-extension formulahendry.auto-rename-tag
code --install-extension formulahendry.code-runner
code --install-extension MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-es
code --install-extension ms-vscode.live-server
code --install-extension oderwat.indent-rainbow
code --install-extension PKief.material-icon-theme
code --install-extension pranaygp.vscode-css-peek
code --install-extension ritwickdey.LiveServer
code --install-extension rvest.vs-code-prettier-eslint
code --install-extension streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
code --install-extension streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker-spanish
code --install-extension tal7aouy.icons
code --install-extension usernamehw.errorlens
```

Comment: @user Resolved! I had a command added in the keybindings.json (which I didn't add). It seems that it has happened to several people. It's a bug in the new vscode update. Thank you!

Comment: i added the code list on the post

Comment: Can confirm, happened the same to me. I just opened `keybindings.json` and removed the command set on `"."`